# LinkedIn API 401 Unauthorised when using Field Selectors

Tags: c#, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I am attempting to get specific information from the user's profile via the LinkedIn API.

The URL I am using for the GET call is the following:

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,industry,headline,public-profile-url)

When attempting this I get a "401 Unauthorized" response from the server. However, when I do a GET to http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~ within the same function with the same auth keys, etc. it works just fine.

The error presented in the response is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error>
  <status>401</status>
  <timestamp>1316082986700</timestamp>
  <request-id>SVWTG5ARQM</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>[unauthorized].</message>
</error>
```

Any ideas of why this might be happening? Anything would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely your OAuth library is buggy. Can you view the full request and response?

I would make sure your Authorization / OAuth header has the same signature as the one generated from this tool:

https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console

If not, you'll need to get a new library, update/fix your library, etc.

If yes, then that is weird. Come back and we'll go from there :)

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for your reply. I'm using RestSharp at the moment. It seems that it does indeed generate an incorrect signature when using field selectors. It's probably the library, as you said. I haven't yet found a workaround though.